# PHP doesn't work properly when hosted

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a Log in and Sign up system and on my localhost it worked properly but when i hosted it and created account it says Incorrect credentials. I will send a code if it is needed. And i have crated a MySql db.

Site link: http://metallicafanpage.esy.es

I am using Hostinger

```
    <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 // it will never let you open index(login) page if session is set
 if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
  header("Location: home.php");
  exit;
 }

 $error = false;

 if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) { 

  // prevent sql injections/ clear user invalid inputs
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $email = strip_tags($email);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

  $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
  $pass = strip_tags($pass);
  $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);
  // prevent sql injections / clear user invalid inputs

  if(empty($email)){
   $error = true;
   $emailError = "Please enter your email address.";
  } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
   $error = true;
   $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
  }

  if(empty($pass)){
   $error = true;
   $passError = "Please enter your password.";
  }

  // if there's no error, continue to login
  if (!$error) {

   $password = hash('sha256', $pass); // password hashing using SHA256

   $res=mysql_query("SELECT userId, userName, userPass FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
   $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

   if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password ) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userId'];
    header("Location: home.php");
       } else {
        $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
       }

      }

     }
    ?>
```

Here is Register.php

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
 include_once 'dbconnect.php';

 $error = false;

 if ( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ) {

  // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
  $name = trim($_POST['name']);
  $name = strip_tags($name);
  $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $email = strip_tags($email);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

  $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
  $pass = strip_tags($pass);
  $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

  // basic name validation
  if (empty($name)) {
   $error = true;
   $nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
  } else if (strlen($name) < 3) {
   $error = true;
   $nameError = "Name must have atleat 3 characters.";
  } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
   $error = true;
   $nameError = "Name must contain alphabets and space.";
  }

  //basic email validation
  if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
   $error = true;
   $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
  } else {
   // check email exist or not
   $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
   if($count!=0){
    $error = true;
    $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
   }
  }
  // password validation
  if (empty($pass)){
   $error = true;
   $passError = "Please enter password.";
  } else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
   $error = true;
   $passError = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
  }

  // password encrypt using SHA256();
  $password = hash('sha256', $pass);

  // if there's no error, continue to signup
  if( !$error ) {

   $query = "INSERT INTO users(userName,userEmail,userPass) VALUES('$name','$email','$password')";
   $res = mysql_query($query);

   if ($res) {
    $errTyp = "success";
    $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
    unset($name);
    unset($email);
    unset($pass);
   } else {
    $errTyp = "danger";
    $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later..."; 
   } 

  }


 }
?>
```

Comment: yes. show your code.

Comment: there is the code @SanzeebAryal. If you need more just write i will send you. This is very important for me.

Comment: how are the users registered? Note: mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: i will show you register code. @SanzeebAryal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is Because Of Your Php Mysql version Your Hosting Server Is Just Using An Old Php Or Mysql Version